# Understanding type deduction with decltype

Tags: c++, reference

Consider following c++ code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

template <typename T> void print_type() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }

class Base{
    int num;
public:
    Base() : num{0} {}

    friend std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream& stream, Base & obiekt){
        stream<< "num: " << obiekt.num;
        return stream;
    }
};

int main(){
    Base a{};
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "type of a: " << std::endl;
    print_type < decltype( a ) > (); 

    std::cout << "type of (a): " << std::endl;
    print_type < decltype( (a) ) > ();


    Base b();
    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    std::cout << "type of b: " << std::endl;
    print_type < decltype( b ) > (); 

    std::cout << "type of (b): " << std::endl;
    print_type < decltype( (b) ) > (); 


    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it with g++ 7.2.0, and got following output:

```
num: 0
type of a: 
void print_type() [with T = Base]
type of (a): 
void print_type() [with T = Base&]
1
type of b: 
void print_type() [with T = Base()]
type of (b): 
void print_type() [with T = Base (&)()]
```

My questions:

- Why `std::cout << b << std::endl;` prints "1"?
- What is a type like `Base()` or `Base (&)()`?
- Why type of `(a)` is `Base&`, when `a` has type `Base`?

I am looking for answer and I can't find it. I know in this case I should use declarations like `Base a;` without any brackets, but i want to know about difference between `Base a;`, `Base a{};` and `Base a();`. Why it copiles without any warnings or errors?
Thanks for help.

Comment: I believe `b` is declared as function returning `Base`. The `cout` converts `b` to a `bool` - hence, the output of `1`. (Consider, that `a` is printed as `num: 0` in opposition to `b`.) (But, I'm not quite sure. I'm looking forward for other comments and the answer.)

Comment: This might be surprising as there is no definition of function `b()`. On the other hand, it's never called. If you try to call it (and I'm on the right track) this should bring a _link_ (instead of compile) error...

Comment: Adding to Scheff's explanations, this is an example of what Scott Meyers named "Most Vexing Parse". You would find even a wikipedia article about this. It looks like declaring a variable, but the compiler parses a function declaration.

Comment: My mate said that Microsoft VS studio not compiles it.  `print_type < decltype( b() ) > (); ` prints type `Base` so Scheff might be right. But what about answer on third question (type `Base&`)

Comment: @Scheff I am wondering why gcc even compiles and links it as `b` seems to be ODR-used... Probably, I am too sleepy and overlook something obvious.

Comment: @EdgarRokjān Yepp. That's why "I'm not quite sure." ;-) On the other hand, it's `g++ 7.2.0` (in words version **seven**). May be, something very modern kicks in which is beyond my imagination...

Comment: @nonamenick regarding your third question, my guess is that you are applying the operator parentheses and it is returning you a reference to the object a. Thats why you see the "&", to point that "reference" status

Comment: Your mate is right. Good reading reading on that here: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Thanks for answers.
@user4581301 Heh, my mate didn't copy it brainlessly. He changed includes. I know i shouldn't use `<bits/stdc++.h>` but when i am learning or debuging it is comfortable, but thanks for advice and article. 

@JorgeY. When i checked type of int in parentheses i got int reference as well. It should be `int&` ?

Comment: I would say so. And the link  from en.cpp.reference that Edgar posted in his elaborated answer seems to confirm it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is that:

```
Base b();
```

doesn't do what you think. In fact, it is a declaration of a function which accepts zero arguments and returns an object of type `Base`.

---

> Why std::cout << b << std::endl; prints "1"?

Because `b` is a pointer to a function. As a result, an overload:

```
basic_ostream& operator<<( bool value );
```

is used and `1` is printed as a pointer to a function is never null.

*A more interesting question is why gcc even accepts the code and produces only a warning. There is no definition for function `b`, only its declaration, so I expected the code not to link.*

---

> What is a type like Base() or Base (&)()?

`Base()` is a pointer to a function accepts no arguments and return `Base`, `Base (&)()` is a reference to the same function.

---

> Why type of (a) is Base&, when a has type Base?

Because `decltype` [works so](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype):

```
decltype(expression)
```

> If the argument is an **unparenthesized** id-expression or an
>   unparenthesized class member access expression, then decltype yields
>   the type of the entity named by this expression. If there is no such
>   entity, or if the argument names a set of overloaded functions, the
>   program is ill-formed.
>
> If the argument is any other expression of type T, and
>
> a) if the value category of expression is xvalue, then decltype yields
>   T&&;
>
> b) **if the value category of expression is lvalue, then decltype
>   yields T&**;
>
> c) if the value category of expression is prvalue, then
>   decltype yields T.